# Loop для html5 video

Tags: html5, видео

Необходимо добавить к `html5` видео функцию `loop`

```
var vid = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0]

vid.loop = true;
```

такой метод работает только к 1 видео или другому по счету в зависимости от цифры указанной тут [0].

Как расширить функцию ко всем элементам с тегом `video` на странице?

Comment: так у тега `video` есть атрибут `loop` который проигрывает видео каждый раз когда оно закончится.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов вопрос про то как перебрать массив

Comment: @StrangerintheQ понятно спасибо .Я просто не внимательно прочитал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```js
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(videos, function(element) {
    element.loop = true;
});
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!